# Error while running allure-junit example

Tags: maven, junit4, allure

I am trying to integrate allure-report with my junit code.
To try this, i was first trying to run the allure-junit example from https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example

When i run this code, i get the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-       plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project SampleAllureTest: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.register(ZZI)V
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.properties.decorators.DefaultFieldDecorator.<init>(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:24)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.properties.PropertyLoader.populate(PropertyLoader.java:29)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.properties.PropertyLoader.populate(PropertyLoader.java:23)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.config.AllureConfig.<init>(AllureConfig.java:80)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.config.AllureConfig.newInstance(AllureConfig.java:84)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.Allure.getVersion(Allure.java:266)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.Allure.fire(Allure.java:187)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener.testSuiteFinished(AllureRunListener.java:89)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener.testRunFinished(AllureRunListener.java:95)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testRunFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:42)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$2.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:103)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestRunFinished(RunNotifier.java:100)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:131)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Could anyone please help me in fixing this issue.Please note, i didnt do any changes to the code in the sample.

Comment: Could you attach your pom.xml as well please? Looks like there's something wrong with your surefire plugin.

Comment: Thank you @Thibstars. After downloading latest example, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [commons-beanutils](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils) to your dependencies.